# Rails Cookie detection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

Hi i'm newbie with rails amd just realized that my Rails App that i created with a beginner tutorial needs cookies to work properly, otherwise after submiting a form it gives the error ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken.

How can i implement in an easy way a cookie detection?

Answer (score 1):

InvalidAuthenticityToken means that you're not sending the correct CSRF token with your form.  You should be building your form with the built-in Rails methods.  These cause a hidden `authenticity_token` input to be inserted into your form.  Rails will verify the `authenticity_token` when the form is submitted.

What leads you to believe that 'cookie detection' is part of the problem?

Comment: Hi Bob, i think we misunderstood each other. The authenticity_token is implemented in the form and activated and works, but just when the user allows cookies for the page. The problem is when cookies aren't allowed to set. It gives the InvalidAuthenticityToken error page. I'm searching for a simple way to implent a dectection if the user has enabled cookies, so if not i would like to show him a message to turn cookies on so that the page works properly.

Comment: don't you think the problem is caused by disabled cookies?

Comment: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/187822 confirms that this seems to be a cookie problem

Comment: Right, CSRF requires a session store because you have to verify that the token was issued to the user.  The obvious alternative is to turn CSRF off or use some other state mechanism if you really can't use cookies.  However, other state mechanisms are not supported natively in Rails.

Comment: Hi Bob, i don't want to turn it off. i thought about a solution like mentioned here http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=40755 unfortunately this code seems not to work: def new
  flash.now[:alert] = "You need to enable cookies!" if params[:cookies_disabled] == "1"
end

Comment: CSRF protection requires some form of state to be maintained.  Cookies are the standard mechanism here.  You could use an alternate state management mechanism to circumvent the fact that your users have turned off cookies, but I don't recommend this.  The correct thing to do is detect that cookies are being rejected and yell at your users.  The user has made it clear that they don't want to be tracked, and you need to manage state.  Those two goals are at odds with each other and attempting to circumvent this by doing something crazy like evercookies is not a great outcome.